# Simple hash bang example in Angular. Why is it not working?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

html:

```
<a href="#!foo">foo</a>
<a href="#!bar">bar</a>
<div ng-view></div>
```

js:

```
angular.module('theApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider)  {
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
        $routeProvider
            .when('/foo', {
                title: 'foo',
                controller: 'foo'
            })
            .when('/bar', {
                title: 'bar',
                controller: 'bar'
            })
    })
    .controller('foo', function(){
        console.log('foo');
    })
    .controller('bar', function(){
        console.log('GGGGG');
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sprhgucv/

Please could somebody let me know **why do I not see anything logged when I click between the links**?

I've only found one good example and that is what I have tried to implement but to no avail: http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js//urls-routing-and-partials/client-side-routing-with-hashbang-urls.html

Comment: You need to include angular-route.js file.

Comment: I have done locally, granted I didn't in the fiddle though. Please can you show me the fiddle with logging working

Comment: You also need ng-app. I've try to fix the fiddle but got errors.

Comment: Not sure right off hand but I believe if you're going to use the hashbang, then you need to add `$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);` before `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');`. Also, if you define your routes like `/foo` then I believe your anchor tag should be `<a href="#!/foo">...` as well. I can't quite get your fiddle working and unfortunately, I don't have the time to look at it any more right now. Those are a few things I noticed though that may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to include angular-route.  Also, I couldn't get it to work without providing some sort of template, but otherwise your code should work.  Here's a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y93oxopg/

```
routingExample.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
$routeProvider.
when('/home', {
    template: '<div>HERE</div>',
    controller: 'HomeController'
}).
when('/about', {
    template: '<div>HERE2</div>',
    controller: 'AboutController'
}).
otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/home'
});
```

});